# Ajax POST запрос выдаёт ошибку: unexpected end of input

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Сам код:

```
function add_post(){
      var fd = new FormData();
      var title=$('textarea#title').val();
      var type=$('input[name=type]:checked', '#post_form').val();

      fd.append('title',  title);      
      fd.append('type', type);
      if (type=='img')
        fd.append('file', $('#file')[0].files[0]); 
      else if (type=='txt'){
        var text=$('textarea#text').val();
        var text=$('textarea#text').val();
        fd.append('text', text);
      }

      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
         url: '/script/ajax/post_add.php',
         data: fd,
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(data) {
           if (data.status=='ok') {
         window.location='post.php?id='+data.id;
          } else 
          if (data.status=='err'){
         if (data.msg=='not_autorized') window.location='reg.html';
         $("#status_div").html('<br><b>Ошибка: '+data.msg+'</b>');
          }

         }
      });
     }          
}
```

Comment: на какой строке?

Comment: у вас post.php заголовок Content-length:  не генерирует где-нить в коде ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var type=$('input[type="radio"]:checked', '#post_form').val();
```

или

```
var type=$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked', '#post_form').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Где вы видите эту ошибку? В коде даже неудачный запрос не обрабатывается.
По сообщению похоже на то, что сервер возвратил данные в некорректном формате. Ожидается, что сервер должен выдать данные в формате JSON. Возможно, "unexpected end of input" - ошибка синтаксического разбора?